# maximisation of value of a function under constraints

Tags: optimization

Let $x,y$ and $z$ be positive real numbers . What is the maximum value of $xyz$ under the constraints $x^2+z^2=1$ and  $y-x=0$ 
Please explain the process.

Comment: You have $y=x$, so essentially you are maximizing $x^2z$ on a unit circle. Does that help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the last equation, we know that $x=y$.  From the second equation we know that $x^2=1-z^2$. Thus we are interested in the maximum of

$$xyz=x^2z=(1-z^2)z$$

It's derivative set equal to $0$:

$$0=1-3z^2\implies3z^2=1\implies z^2=\frac13\implies z=\sqrt\frac13$$

Thus, the maximum value is

$$xyz\le\left(1-\frac13\right)\sqrt\frac13=\frac23\sqrt\frac13$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, as mentioned by @Shailesh, you are maximizing a function over a unit circle.

More precisely, the intersection of $x^2+z^2=1$ and $y=x$ is the curve which can be parametrized as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\cos t\\
y(t)=x(t)=\cos t\quad\quad \mbox{with }t\in [0,2\pi]\\
z(t)=\sin t
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the function that you are maximizing can be expressed as
$$
x(t)y(t)z(t)=\cos^2(t)\sin(t),
$$
which has maximum $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$.